# Compiler thinks Comparable type is not Comparable

Tags: java, generics, interface, comparable

So I have a class that implements Comparable (I have a dummy method here for brevity)

```
public class MarkovEntry<T extends Chainable> implements Comparable<MarkovEntry<T>>
{
    // Compare two rows by ID
    public int compareTo(MarkovEntry<T> e)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

And a method in another class that takes a Comparable (once again, dummy method)

```
public class ArrayOps
{
    public static int binSearch(ArrayList<Comparable> list, Comparable c)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Yet when I try to call my method as follows

```
int index = ArrayOps.binSearch(entries, newEntry);
```

Where entries is an ArrayList of MarkovEntry's and newEntry is a MarkovEntry, the compiler tells me

```
actual argument java.util.ArrayList<com.company.MarkovEntry<T>> cannot be converted 
to java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.Comparable> by method invocation.
```

What is going on here?  MarkovEntry specifically implements Comparable -- why doesn't the compiler recognize that?

My class Chainable implements Comparable as well, in case that has anything to do with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generics are a little strange in that

```
ArrayList<SuperType>
```

is not actually a supertype of

```
ArrayList<SubType>
```

e.g. `ArrayList<Number>` is not a supertype of `ArrayList<Integer>`. This is because if such a relationship held you could substitute in an `ArrayList<Number>` for an `ArrayList<Integer>`, which would then allow operations that would have been illegal if you didn't make the replacement.

To be more specific, say you did this:

```
ArrayList<Number> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

You'd then be able to put in a `Double` into `list` because to the compiler, `list` is an `ArrayList<Number>`! As you can see, this breaks the guarantees that generics should provide, so it isn't allowed.

---

What you're looking for is a *generic method* like this:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> int binSearch(ArrayList<T> list)
```

Basically, you can generify methods the same way you can generify classes.

More info can be found here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html

Comment: No need for a generic method here; Just use a [wildcard](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html): `int binarySearch(ArrayList<? extends Comparable> list)`

Comment: Wait, wouldn't `Comparable` need to be parametrized?

Comment: for best results use `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>`

Comment: `binSearch(ArrayList<? extends Comparable<?>> list)` will not be type safe

Comment: @newacct I knew something was missing... Thanks!